# phpmyadmin not working with xdebug, netbeans and xampp

Tags: php, netbeans, phpmyadmin, xampp, xdebug

I search and search by Google and I didn't find anything useful.
After I debug the first time in Netbeans, I cannot enter to phpmyadmin. 
I tried to change the next settings. I have PHP Version 5.6.15 and Xampp is 3.2.2.

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

And

```
xdebug.collect_return="0"
```

But I don't find where to change it, so I added that lines to the php.ini but it doesn't work. So I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

[Enabling XDebug in XAMPP slows down phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893010/enabling-xdebug-in-xampp-slows-down-phpmyadmin)
[enabling xdebug remote debug makes apache server very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736304/enabling-xdebug-remote-debug-makes-apache-server-very-slow)
[Problems with database links on phpmyadmin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482099/problems-with-database-links-on-phpmyadmin-interface)

Comment: I found the solution very easy. Everywhere says that you must restart apache, but it worked out when I restart the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the version of xdebug to the current one: `Xdebug 2.5.0` 
I followed the instructions at this link: `https://xdebug.org/wizard.php`

Then I put this in **php.ini**:

```
;Xdebug

zend_extension="C:\Ampps\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.5-vc11.dll"

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_enable= 1

;xdebug.remote_hadnler = "dbgp" ;es valor por defecto

;xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1;es valor por defecto

;xdebug.remote_port=9000;es valor por defecto

xdebug.trace_output_dir= "c:\ampps\tmp"
```